# Can't connect to Nextcloud from GNOME Online Accounts or Nautilus

Tags: linux, networking, gnome, nextcloud, tailscale

I'm trying to add my Nextcloud account to GNOME to be able to mount it. However, it never works. Seems like it has an issue when connecting to internal or private IP's, and not public ones.

I am using Tailscale, which creates a network, giving all your devices a private IP. In the web browser, Linux and Android Nextcloud app, I can use the private IP given to my server to access it, and it works fine. However, when I try to add the Nextcloud account to GNOME from the settings app, it just freezes and never loads.
[image: Trying to add Nextcloud account from Settings]

If I try to mount it directly from Nautilus, with davs://server/nextcloud , davs://192.168.0.92/nextcloud (The Tailscale Private IP), or 192.168.0.5/nextcloud (The real private IP, not the one from Tailscale) I get this error:

[image: Error when trying to mount Nextcloud directly from Nautilus]

I tried to install other file managers to see if they can connect. With Caja and Nemo, which as far as I know, are based on Nautilus, show this error, preventing from even entering the server's address:

[image: Trying to connect to server from other file browser]